# Windows: unexpected power button behavior

Tags: windows, power-management

The semantics of hardware power button is as simple as that: when it is ON it switches OFF, when it is OFF it switches ON. And now some UI geniuses have perverted even this function. When it is ON, but monitor is OFF it turns monitor ON, not turns computer OFF. Thanks to those geniuses, many times I left my computers ON along the whole night. Now, to overcome this lame situation, I need either to be aware of monitor status, which is very inconvenient, not to say unacceptable, or to always press power button twice to switch OFF. To switch ON I still need to press it once, otherwise it will turn it OFF immediately. As you can see, semantics of power button is now inconsistent. What can we do to revert back to good old behavior?

Comment: How about just using the shutdown button in your operating system? Also, computers usually have a power indicator.

Comment: This is even worse, than pressing power button twice.

Comment: Common mistake some members make is formatting. Many people will not read a huge bock of difficult to read text. Taking a minute to [edit] your question to make it easier to read, and by removing the rant, will increase your chances of getting the help you seek. It would be nice to know what "UI" you are referring to and what version of Windows this involves.

Comment: Sorry, I want to rant. I don't believe there is any decent solution except for hacking binaries. I hope someone at Microsoft will finally stumble upon this.

Comment: This isn't a place for ranting. It's not a forum. That being said, I'm getting the impression your PC is in standby mode.

Comment: It's not in standby mode. Only monitor in standby mode.

Comment: Visit your geniuses with a baseball bat.

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible.

Comment: Stop using computers, you obviously should stay clear of them....

Comment: Actually, rant aside, Windows 10 does have some very inconsistent behaviour when it comes to shutting it down. WinKey/X, U, U ought to do it, but only if the first press brings up the menu, which it doesn't always, depending on what else is frontmost. Many is the time I return to a headless machine the following day to find it's still on.

Comment: I'm saying about 8, but sure that this moronism comes from 7 or Vista and is not fixed in 10. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.